# Parse method or overload the constructor

Tags: c#, .net

When writing a method that takes a string and populates a poco based on it, is it better to have a static `Parse(string s)` method like `Int32.Parse()` or overload the constructor so it takes a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer the constructor version, but including both is easy, since the constructor can just call `Parse`. This is the pattern followed by the `Guid` struct (and likely others as well.)

I should add that if you're not dealing with a `struct`, then the `static` method should probably be referring to the constructor (or even a separate method that both can call) since you can't assign to `this` in a `class` constructor.

**EDIT**: As TrueWill points out, if you do include `Parse`, you should include `TryParse` as well. Incidentally, `Guid` is once again instructive: the `Parse` method actually uses `TryParse`, and just throws an exception if `TryParse` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If the method might fail due to an invalid string, I'd lean towards Parse and include [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) as per the [TryParse pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx).

Comment: +1 for TryParse though id still go for dlevs both but with a try parse as well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using .Parse(string s) if its a simple object, if the object stores more then 1-2 values you should use the constructor, or in other words, dont parse if the return value will be an instance with memebers unaffected by the parse value.